# Ubiquitous framework to target multiple smartphone OS?

Tags: smartphone

Is there already a ubiquitous/general framework to target multiple smartphone OS, i.e. like a QT for Android/iPhone/Symbian? Or would be technically too hard to write such a framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Phonegap if it fits your needs. Packages a web app with limited access to device services as an installable.

Comment: this lead me into the right direction, i also found http://www.appcelerator.com/ and http://rhomobile.com/

I'm going to analyze the frameworks and see which one i'll take.

Answer (score 1):

Technically it would be pretty much impossible (at least very difficult).

The first problem is that the mentioned platforms don't share a common language, so you wouldn't be able to directly share source code. Second is that your abstraction layer would have to be so big that it would probably kill performance.

The closest thing that I'm aware of is something like OpenGL es (you can *almost* copy & paste OpenGL code across platforms).

A more realistic option is targeting the web layer with an HTML5 application.